# Page Centering in IE9 not working

Tags: internet-explorer-9

For the life of me I can't get just the HOME PAGE of this site to center on the browser for IE9. Every internal page centers fine, and all other browsers and versions seem to be working fine as well. What am I missing? Is there a fix for this?

See: http://www.newlandmarkgroup.com/index_test2.php

Also the dropdown nav items don't seem to be appearing ONLY in IE9 since I've implemented the jQuery image scroller, but that's a separate issue!